# Certain downloaded PDFs cause upload error ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a strange issue with a project I have inherited - ASP (VB.net).

There is a file upload section on the site that documents are uploaded to.

When a document is downloaded from adobe scan (PDF from adobecloud.adobe.com) and uploaded it causes an error.

HOWEVER if the file is copied and uploaded (even if renamed so it is uploaded with the same name) it will work.

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: Is it truly just a raw file upload, or is there some post processing going on after the server receives the file? For example, I have an uploader for users to upload PDFs, but after uploading I run a verification method to ensure the uploaded file truly is a PDF, and not just a file with a .pdf extension.

Comment: Uses a file collection, loops the collection, checks the content length > 0, filename isnt blank and that is it. It then checks if the file exists and if it doesn't uses .saveAs to save it. Nothing I can see that would indicate any particular post processing but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: - check the file attributes
- check the file security
- try another file

Comment: Check with adobecloud people too.

Comment: thanks for the comments, to clarify this is multiple files. Normal files work fine this system has been in use a long time, it just seems to be certain PDFs (which are 'scans' created by a mobile phone camera and converted to scans by adobe). It is also not every file that is downloaded from Adobe Cloud. For security - what can Adobe set for a file download in the documents security settings that would be lost when the file is copied so I know what to look for?